# unite between 2 tables and group by a third one

Tags: mysql

I explain...

I have the table A and the table B. I need to show a.user from A and b.group from B and there is a third table where appears which user in each group

Table C.

```
userId    groupId
1            1
1            2
2            1
3            2
```

So I need to groupby on a the third table showing the names of the user and groups that appears in the other two tables.

Sincerily I dont have the level to do this. Just to show you what I've tried embarrasses me :(

Please help

Comment: Please learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: First of all, do not be embarrassed to show your work, we're here to help! Second, we'll need a better example/explanation. Can you provide us with some sample data for your tables? and what is your expected outcome? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that I understood the question. Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEC C
GROUPBY [userId], [groupId]
WHERE
    (C.[userId] in select [userId] from TABLEA) and
    (C.[groupId] in select [groupId] from TABLEB)
```